# How to change button color when it is active?

Tags: python, html, css

[image]

[image: s]

This is my code:

```
<div class="shell-container"><br>
      <center><a href="{{instagram_url}}"style="margin:-3.5px; background-color: #e4405f" class="button btn btn-block btn-instagram"> <i style="margin: 0 5px 0 0;" class="fab fa-instagram"></i>    Sígueme en Instagram </a><br></center>
    </div>
```

And this is my "button" class

```
.button{
    border-radius: 6px;
    width:275px;
    color: white
  }
```

The problem is that whenever y put my cursor on the link or when I click it, the font automatically gets black and I don't want this to happen. I would like only to be white as the first image. Thanks advance

Comment: .button:hover, .button:focus {
    color: white
 }

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani please move your comment to an answer to get credit for it.

Comment: @rawnewdlz this kind of questions are so simple, so the person who asks can credit in comment by arrow top ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.button:hoover, .button:focus {     
    color:white;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no other css rules have more specificity power, this would keep your button text always white:

.button:hover,
.button:active,
.button:focus {
    color: white
  }

It is generally a good practice to differentiate the visibility of the different states though, as it gives the user feedback on what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The default color for a 'visited' or clicked link, is purple in most browsers. It looks like you have another CSS rule that is making your visited and hover links turn black. You can find an example of how to change this below:

```
.button:visited,
.button:hover,
.button:a {
  color: white
}
```

Notice that you can group similar rules together by comma separating them.